# What does the "status-completed" tag mean on "discussion" questions? How does it compare to/contrast with an answer being accepted?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

It seems I'd left this tab open on my phone a week ago because it intrigued/confused me.

What does the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag denote in the context of questions tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)?

I'm thinking that it means no further discussion is required, sufficient consensus has been reached and action has (or has not) been taken in accordance with that consensus. Is that about right?

Should each question's author now consider accepting an answer for an even higher degree of "closure"?

[image: status-completed] click for larger (probably not necessary)

Comment: can't suggest an edit, but use `[meta-tag:status-completed]` as markdown to link to the meta's tag ;)

Comment: @ymb1 *thank you very much!* I kind of puzzled me how the system would know in which site to find the tag, and so it turns out that it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only use the status-completed tag on a discussion if there is some mod action required, and really only on tag questions pretty much. All it means is that the mod action has been completed. It doesn't necessarily mean more discussion can't happen, though in cases where mod action has already been taken, it's probably better to start a new meta discussion if what you want to discuss is a significant change from the mod action taken.

It's different from "accept" because the asker decides which answer to accept based on what they personally feel is mostly helpful, which may not necessarily reflect what mod action was taken.